# Turn on x-axis and y-axis values when printing several rasters leveplot R

Tags: r, maps, raster, axis-labels, levelplot

I would like to turn on the x and y-axis values (i.e. label the empty tick marks) in the following example:

```
library(rasterVis)
s <- stack(replicate(6, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))
levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)))
```

In the actual data, I will be labelling the empty tickmarks using lat and lon.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(rasterVis)
s <- stack(replicate(6, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))

x.scale <- list(font=10,
                fontface=2,
                alternating=1)

y.scale <- list(font=10,
                fontface=2,
                alternating=1)

levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)),
  scales = list(x=x.scale, y=y.scale))
```

[image]

Comment: `levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)), scales=list(alternating=FALSE))` will also do the trick.

Comment: @jbaums  Yes. Just wanted to also show to OP more controls.